# targeting words in a line of text

Tags: python, string, text-files, readline, targeting

I have identified a line in a text file that looks like this:

```
FLAGS                    = WORD1 WORD2 WORD3
```

I am reading several files in which the number of words can vary from 0 to a maximum of 3.

I'm using this code:

```
flag_FLAG = 0
for i in range(len(materialfile)):
    if  "FLAG" in materialfile[i] and "=" in materialfile[i]:
        line_FLAG = i
        flag_FLAG = 1
        
    if flag_FLAG == 1:
        
        temp = materialfile[line_FLAG].split(" ")
        for elem in temp:
            if is_word(elem):
                flags = str(elem)
```

unfortunately this way I only get one word (the last one).
"is_word" is a function that i creat:

```
def is_word(s):
    try:
        str(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

I would like to get all the words as targets.
I hope I have been clear.

Answer (score 1):

You want a nested loop, e.g.:

```
materialfile = [
    "FLAGS                    = WORD1 WORD2 WORD3",
]

flags = [
    flag
    for line in materialfile if "FLAGS" in line and "=" in line
    for flag in line.split(" = ")[1].split() if flag
]

print(flags)  # ['WORD1', 'WORD2', 'WORD3']
```

Hard to say whether this exact code will work with your actual file, since you didn't provide a sample file, but hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Note that your `is_word` function does nothing since these are already strings and will hence always convert to `str()` as a no-op without raising an exception.  The `if flag` in the above comprehension will filter out values of `flag` that are empty (e.g. if you had a line like `FLAGS =` ).

Comment: Unfortunately, the file consists of other lines and I am not able to adapt your script to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

```
for i in range(len(materialfile)):
    if  "FLAGS" in materialfile[i] and "="  in materialfile[i]:
        line_flag = i
        flag_flag = 1
if flag_flag == 1:
    flags = materialfile[line_flag].split(" = ")[1].split()
```

I don't know if this is an elegant way but it seems to work. Thanks

Comment: This seems like it won't work if you have more than one `FLAGS = ...` line...

Comment: remember to accept your own answer unless you're waiting for someone else to post a different solution